# Facebook instant articles: can't enable the "submit for review" button, it's always greyed out

Tags: facebook, wordpress, feed, facebook-instant-articles

I'd like to configure facebook for instant articles with my website (http://www.marcozanetti.it/). I installed three plugins:

- Facebook Instant Articles & Google AMP Pages by PageFrog, in order to get the right styles for posts
- Instant Articles for WP by Automattic, in order to have the http://www.marcozanetti.it/blog/feed/instant-articles feed
- WP-InstantArticles by Lester 'GaMerZ' Chan.

Actually just the second plugin would be enough but I then realized i needed something to style my posts according to instant articles specifications, so I installed Facebook *Instant Articles & Google AMP Pages by PageFrog* as well.

When i generated the feed http://www.marcozanetti.it/blog/feed/instant-articles I noticed it does not contain at least 50 posts as facebook settings require: my website contains far more than 50 posts so I was wondering why was the feed limited to a smaller number; being *Instant Articles for WP* the official wordpress plugin for instant articles I expected it to generate a compliant feed.

In order to get a fuller feed I installed the third plugin and got another feed: http://www.marcozanetti.it/blog/instant-articles This one includes 50 posts but it doesn't work either. I tried pasting both feed URLs in the configuration page

[image]

expecting this to enable the "Submit for review" button, but it does not.

[image]

Did anybody experience similar issues? How did you solve it?

Thank you
Marco

Comment: all your articles might be linking to the same article, double check your URLS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your articles to be visible in your production or development feed you need to update each article once to publish them through the Instant Articles API. You'll see that each article you update will appear instantly in the feed after update.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the [submission checklist](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/checklist) first after that this is what I found by myself during the experiment with FBIA

- Your article must not contains any common errors
- Your article must not contains any wrong syntax structure. For example

  - inside `<p></p>` must has text
  - You cannot include `<figure>` inside `<p>` tag, this will cause image inside the article not display
  - `<figure>` must wrap up `<img>` tag like `<figure><img></figure>`
- Your RSS feed must be all valid
- For GUID in RSS that will be use for FBIA, it must define the attribute `isPermaLink="false"` in order to indicate that GUID is for identification purpose as it use to store the link not an id of the article by default.
- You must have sufficient number of articles that satisfied the review policy (Now is 10 articles)
- Check that each article's canonical url must point to the web version of each article not the rss url
- The default style and your customised style for FBIA must contain your logo
- If you want to use your existing articles, you have to update them to make the modified time most lastest. FBIA will ignore the articles that longer than 24 hours based on op-modified time